# pyspark count with condition with selectExpr

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, select, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with a column "age" and I want to count how many rows with age = 60, for example. I know how to solve this using select or df.count() but I want to use selectExpr.

I tried

```
customerDfwithAge.selectExpr("count(when(col(age) = 60))")
```

but it returns me

```
Undefined function: 'col'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.;
```

If I try to remove *col*, it returns me

```
Invalid arguments for function when; line 1 pos 6
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `selectExpr` you need to provide a valid SQL expression.

`when()` and `col()` are `pyspark.sql.functions` not SQL expressions.

In your case, you should try:

```py
customerDfwithAge.selectExpr("sum(case when age = 60 then 1 else 0 end)")
```

Bear in mind that I am using `sum` not `count`. `count` will count every row (`0`s and `1`s) and it would simply return the total number of rows of your dataframe.